# TapGestureRecognition in Xamarin Forms Listview

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin

I need to check if the empty part of a Xamarin Forms Listview is tapped. For example, there are 5 rows and the space below those filled rows is tapped a method should be called.
I tried adding Tapgesturerecognizer to the Listview and the page containing the listview but this didnt work.
Is there a way to check if someone tapped the empty space in the listview?

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <d:ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>First Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Second Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Third Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Fourth Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Fifth Item</x:String>
                    <x:String>Sixth Item</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </d:ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                d:Text="{Binding .}"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                d:Text="Item descripton"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="13" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"></TapGestureRecognizer> 
            </ListView.GestureRecognizers>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to adding footer to the Listview

```
<ListView
    x:Name="ItemsListView"
    ...>

    <ListView.Footer>
        <ContentView>
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer />
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        </ContentView>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

set footer view and place your `TapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: If it doesn't work try to set `ContentView` `HeightRequest` to specified size

Comment: Thank you both very much! This combination is working fine and is a simple solution

Comment: Now I have the Problem that the HeightRequest is ignored if the ListView fills up the whole screen. Then there is no whitespace at the bottom. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#selection-and-taps. 
it discusses the selection activity in the ListView so u can execute some logic When an item is selected

Update: 
[Remove Code in the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELV5x.png) then configure the ListView item selection as shown in the link.

then put the ListView (make sure that the list view fill only the space it needs) In a StackLayout and Configure the Tapped event of the stackLayout with the logic u need to execute on clicking the empty page.

Comment: I currently have a tap logic for when an item in the listview gets clicked. But I want to handle a click on the empty space below the items.

Comment: i get your point, you should have your ListView in a layout such StackLayout and configure the tap gesture for the StackLayout with the logic u want to be implemented if an empty part is clicked ans set the vertical properties to the ListView to center then ur ListView will only fill the space it needs and the StackLayout handler will control the rest of the page